# Auth.js (ex Next-Auth) combined with Firebase's signInWithEmailAndPassword is driving me crazy

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I'm trying to implement **Firebase Email & Password authentication** using the **CredentialsProvider** from **AuthJs**, but I haven't had any success. The issue arises when I attempt to call the method **signInWithEmailAndPassword**, and I receive the error: **"Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'os' module."** I've searched extensively online but haven't found a successful workaround.

I'm using NextJs 14+ & AuthJs V5.
The structure of the AuthJs in my project is:
*
/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts*

`export { GET, POST } from "@/auth";`

*/src/auth.ts*

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "./auth.config";

export const {
 handlers: { GET, POST },
 auth,
 signIn,
} = NextAuth({
 session: { strategy: "jwt" },
 ...authConfig,
});
```

*/src/auth.config.ts*

```
export default {
 providers: [
     Credentials({
         async authorize(credentials) {
             const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

             if (validatedFields.success) {
             const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;
             await signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebase.auth, email, password)
                 .then((userCredential) => {
                    return userCredential.user;
                  })
                 .catch((error) => {});
             }

             return null;
         },
      }),
 ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround or can recommend a library other than AuthJs that works well with Firebase?

Thanks!

I'm looking for a way to log in using Firebase's `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method and then save the session into the AuthJs library for use in my NextJs 14+ project.

Comment: Why are you using 2 authentication products? Why not use one or the other?